# Planning to go for hosted dialler from UK. Call center is india and they will dial to Australia and USA

Tags: cloud-hosting

Planning to use cloud hosted dialer (megacall.com). The call Center is in India and vendor servers are in UK. Call centers will be calling Australia and USA.. Will there be any latency due to long distance

Comment: What's the speed of light?

Answer (score 1):

No. Whatever technology you use will magically bend the speed of light and get away with latency.

What the heck do you think? if there is latncy bwetween india and trhe UK then obviously the latency will be on the call. And guess what, there is latency because of that little fact called speed of light.

Comment: it will be a voice call center hence will there be any latency in the conversation.. if yes then what is the solution

Comment: @Archi Yes, there will be latency. If you find a solution to the speed of light, do let us know.

Comment: sure. Just would like to know will there be any interruption in the conversation?

Comment: @Archi How many times do we have to say yes for it to sink in? Yes, there will be. Whether it's an acceptable amount is for you to determine.

Comment: Funny. Now the fact that it is voice data will bend the laws of physics.